# How to check if results on while($row = mysql_fetch_array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to figure out how to handle this is no results are returned, how would I code that?

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))

So like if there a results: print them out

else: show a link

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ... }
} else {
  // show link
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to tell you how many results are found. Using that with a simple `if-statement`, and you can determine what action to take.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // do while loop
} else {
  // show link
}
```

Comment: Just wondering - will the resulting value from that function always be falsy if it fails or no results? Could omit the greater than 0 if so (I always have, but have never thought too much in depth about possible return values) +1

Comment: "Return Values: The number of rows in a result set on success or FALSE on failure." It seems that this may return `0` if indeed there are zero results, but `false` if the function fails.

Comment: Excellent. Worked perfectly, better than how I had found.

Answer (score 2):

Others suggest using `mysql_num_rows()` but you should be aware that that function works only if you use a *buffered query*.  If you query using `mysql_unbuffered_query()`, the number of rows in the result is not available.

I would use a simple flag variable:

```
$found_row = false;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $found_row = true;
  . . .
}

if ($found_row == false) {
  // show link
}
```

It may seem redundant to set `$found_row` to true repeatedly, but assigning a literal value to a variable ought to be an insignificant expense in any language.  Certainly it is small compared to fetching and processing an SQL query result.

Comment: Languages should have a construct to avoid this problem, since it's so common. Something like `while($cond){$action}else{$code}`.

Comment: @Mark: Python has a while/else construct.

Answer (score 1):

Use even shorter syntax without insignificant `mysql_num_rows` to save processor time:

```
if($result) {
   // return db results
} else {
   // no result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have figured it out:

```
if (!($row = mysql_fetch_array($descResult)))
     {
     echo "<tr><td>Add Link</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without mysql_num_rows() or an additional (flag) variable

```
if ( false===($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) ) {
  echo 'no rows in result set';
}
else {
  do {
    echo $row['X'];
  } while ( false===($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) );
}
```

but it duplicates the actual fetch command (one in the if-statement and one in the while-clause).